# Repeat code in JSTL

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I need help, I have a JSTL code I need to use it again if a condition is met, such as:

```
<c:forEach items="${arbol.subTree}" var="arbol"> 
name = <c:out value="${arbol.nombre}"/> 
<c:if test="${arbol.subTree!=null}"> 
/ / do the last foreach 
</ c: if> 
</ c: forEach>
```

If anyone can help me, if you have doubt, I'm traveling and need a tree forEach do that every time you have an available node. 
As the trees may have thousands of nodes down, as I call the above code without having to write thousands of times?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSTL is not meant to do any recursive method at all. If you want/need to display a tree, then it would be better passing the tree structure from Java to JavaScript using JSON, then evaluate the JSON object in JavaScript and apply any recursive method you want/need.

In Java, turn your structure into a JSON string. This can be done using jackson:

```
YourTree tree = ...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
request.setAttribute("tree", mapper.writeValueAsString(tree));
```

In JavaScript, get the JSON string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var tree = JSON.parse('${tree}');
        //do what you want/need with your tree structure...
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And how could I do this transformation, not quite understand

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: as I can make the conversion, you could you give me some example?

Comment: @ELíasVargas example posted. I cannot imagine what will you do with your iterative method, though.